# Laravel using translations inside translations

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say I have the following translation in `App\resources\lang\en\validation.php`:

```
'different' => 'The attribute "' . __('strings.:attribute') . '" cannot be the same as the ":other" attribute',
```

My problem is here:

```
__('strings.:attribute')
```

This will not be translated. If I do the following manually to test:

```
__('strings.something')
```

The translation does work. My question is, how to make it work with `__('strings.:attribute')` and why doesn't it work the way I am trying to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep in mind that there is two different contexts :

- When your translations are actually required by the framework
- When the translation string is actually used and attributes replaced

Attributes needs to be part of the resulting string to be replaced, they can't be part of your php code

so something like :

```
__('strings.:attribute')
```

cannot work.

If what you want to do, is rename attributes in validation messages, you can do that with laravel :

validation.php

```
'different' => 'The attribute ":attribute" cannot be the same as the ":other" attribute',
'attributes' => [
   // your attributes
   'something' => 'MySomething'
]
```

You will have an error that looks like :

```
{"something.different": "The attribute \"MySomething\" cannot be the same as the \"MyOther\" attribute"}
```

Comment: Ah yes this makes total sense and now I understand what I was doing wrong, thanks for the answer, I will accept it after I have tried it but by the looks of it, it is the correct answer